# Some class is conflicting with my css and i can't figure it out

Tags: css

I'm trying to simply making 3 columns for 50 states like in my jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/efhr833n/

But when i go live. It's the exact code and for some reason there is margin on each subsequent div:

live site: http://unclestevesny.com/test-accordion/
Here's a screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9k7h8d4ku92are/acc.png?dl=0

I have no idea what is making this happen.

```
/* accordion header */
.accordion .thestate {
background:#A91414;
width:250px;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
cursor:pointer;
color: #fff;
margin:15px;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
float:left;
}
```

html
    
     New York
    New York
    New York

```
<span class="thestate">District of Columbia</span>
<span class="thestate">New York</span>
<span class="thestate">New York</span>
</div> <!-- end accordion -->
```

Answer (score 6):

I would say to remove the `<br>` tags and add some `margin-bottom`;

Comment: from where? I have no br tags in my fiddle

Comment: You have br tags on the live site.

Answer (score 1):

In your live site there are `< br/>` tags , so the lines are broken.

Delete the `< br/>` tags and site should work

Comment: OMG, Thank you. i realized Wordpress is automatically adding a <br> tag after every carriage return in my text editor! Fixed. THANK YOU!!